# Finding the variance of nth element in sublist in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for the variance of the first element of each subarray in an array using python.

The data looks like this...

```
INPUT = [[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], [x3, y3, z3], ... [xn, yn, zn]]

# Code magic

OUTPUT = [x_var, y_var, z_var]
```

Is there any pythonic way to do this?

I'm currently doing it this way. Please don't judge too harsh.

```
INPUT = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

OUTPUTx = [item[0] for item in INPUT]
OUTPUTy = [item[1] for item in INPUT]
OUTPUTz = [item[2] for item in INPUT]

OUTPUTx = numpy.var(OUTPUTx)
OUTPUTy = numpy.var(OUTPUTy)
OUTPUTz = numpy.var(OUTPUTz)

OUTPUT = numpy.zeros(3)

OUTPUT[0] = OUTPUTx
OUTPUT[1] = OUTPUTy
OUTPUT[2] = OUTPUTz
```

Comment: If you want variances, why are you computing means?

Comment: sorry, typo... was about to edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the axis in the [var](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) function, from the documentation:

> axis : None or int or tuple of ints, optional Axis or axes along which
>   the variance is computed. The default is to compute the variance of
>   the flattened array.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

INPUT = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(np.var(INPUT, axis=0))
```

**Output**

```
[6. 6. 6.]
```